# Best way to connect to L2TP VPN from container running in GCP

Tags: openvpn, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine, openconnect

I've built an ubuntu container locally that uses OpenConnect to establish a connection to a customer's AnyConnect VPN server.  They also have an L2TP connection available as well.  After OpenConnect establishes a connection, some python code is called to do some data extraction from an MSSQL instance then shut down.

I've been fighting with getting this to work in Cloud Run, which was likely never going to work as there doesn't seem any way to establish a tunnel network device, much less run with any privileges or docker capabilities.

My assumption is either I have to run the container inside Compute Engine, or hopefully there's a way to get this working in App Engine.  But I assume there's a standard way for me to get access to a VPN network (without using Google Cloud VPN) from a container running in GCP, and I haven't found an example much less official documentation from Google on how to accomplish this within their eco system.

Comment: Your only **possible** option is Compute Engine. You do not have the level of network control required in Cloud Run and App Engine. If you are able to set up the VPN connection in Compute Engine, then you can create a connector for Cloud Run to route traffic thru the Compute Engine VPN.